# How to put '<' and '>' inside a linkbutton's text property (asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net

How to put '<' and '>' inside a linkbutton's text property (asp.net)? I tried `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbEdit" Text="&lt;edit settings&gt;"></asp:LinkButton>` but then the link doesn't show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that will render with the exact text `<edit settings>` which the browser will consider another tag.

Try `Text="&amp;lt;edit settings&amp;gt;"`